# 2-3 tree insertion

Tags: data-structures, tree

3 trees at school and after trying to find examples how to insert and build a 2-3 tree the answers that I found were different from what I learned. I want an 2-3 tree with m-1 like the following. I know the answer but I don't know how to build it. Can someone please show me how to build one using these elements which I got in this 2-3 and from where to begin

```
                                    45_

                            14 25        50_

     1 3_   14 17 _   25 27 30            45 _ _   50 57 _
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What have you tried that didn't work? What language are you working in?

Comment: no im not implementing it using a programming language. What i want is that I have those elements listed in the tree and obtain that tree. I only know the result but I don't know how to implement it

Answer (score 0):

2-3 tree can have different no of elements in a particular node. The possible number of children each node can have is 2 0r 3.

Now if the parent consists on on element and has 2 children like

```
                         (a)
                        /   \
                       (b)   (c)
```

Then ba which is what essentially happens in the case of a binary search tree. If the parent consists of 2 elements (a,b) and the children are q, w, e then qb and a

These are the conditions that have t be checked when you are inserting elements in a 2-3 tree. [This](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/cs14/cs14_06win/slides/2-3_trees_covered.pdf) will help you a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an implementation of a 2 3 tree at [Implementing a 2 3 Tree in C++](http://cplusplus.kurttest.com/notes/tree23.html).